# echo only the selected value in PHP

Tags: php, html, selected

In the code at the end, the line:

```
<td class="center-align"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
```

shows an html dropdown list with a selected value. What should I do to show  only the value selected within the dropdown list, whthout the dropdown list box?

-This is a link to what it shows now:

http://oi57.tinypic.com/wqzf5x.jpg

-This is what I want to show:

http://oi62.tinypic.com/k2efra.jpg

Here is the code:

```
<tbody>
<?php foreach ($products as $product): ?>
  <tr>
  <td class="purchase_deal_title" colspan="2">

 <?php 
 $deal = Group_Buying_Deal::get_instance($product['deal_id']);
  echo $deal->get_title($product['data']); ?>
    </td>
<td class="center-align"><?php echo $product['quantity']; ?></td>
<td class="cart-price"><?php echo gb_formatted_money($product['unit_price']); ?></td>

</tr>

<?php endforeach ?>

</tbody>
```

Comment: in both screen shot what is the difference?

Comment: My best guess is that your `$product` variable contains a pre-made `select` field. Based on your given code, that's the only place the dropdown could be coming from. We would need to see where the variable is defined to help you.

Comment: there is no drop down code at all in your code and in screen shot it also not shown. thanks. if it already made then show code of that part

Comment: Links are not showing anything

Comment: Strange. The links work on my end. If you got the same page I did, try clicking "Zoom" on the left.

Comment: did you solve your problem?